# Cakephp Insert Ignore Feature?

Tags: cakephp, model, insert

Is there a way to do an "insert ignore" in cake without using a model->query function?

```
            $this->Model->save(array(
                'id' => NULL,
                'guid' => $guid,
                'name' => $name,
            ));
```

Generates error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1062: Duplicate entry 'GUID.....' for key 'unique_guid' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 524]
```

It would be great to be able to set some flag or option that says "don't care"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really an `INSERT IGNORE` solution, but to handle this situation at the app level you'd use validation rules. If you simply attach the `isUnique` validation rule ([*2.x*](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#simple-rules)) ([*3.x*](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules)) to the `guid` field in your model, Cake will automatically bail out of the save operation if the guid already exists.

Behind the scenes it'll make two queries to the database instead of the one that `INSERT IGNORE` would produce, but that shouldn't be a big problem.

A problem may be that it'll return `false` for these failed operations and you'll have to use `$this->Model->invalidFields()` to figure out what the problem was and if you can ignore it. You could override `Model::save()` to do this within the model so you don't have to do it every time in the controller.

You may also want to use `$this->Model->isUnique(array('guid' => $guid))` ([*2.x*](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique)) ([*3.x*](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules)) to check manually before you save. Again, you could override the `save` method and have it silently return `true` if the guid is not unique, but be careful with this sort of thing.

Comment: I agree it looks like I need look into other options. For my situation I ended up need to query again anyway so this is perfect (isUnique). I wasn't aware that there was such a function

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's such a simple flag or option in CakePHP since this warning is originally generated by MySql,not cake itself.If you don't need unique feature on `guid` you have to do some index altering query.E.g

```
$this->Model->query("ALTER TABLE `yourdatebasename`.`yourtablename` DROP INDEX `guid` ,ADD INDEX `guid` ( `guid` )");
```

Comment: So Pretty much "no solution?"

Comment: I'm afraid to make Mysql say 'i don't care' you have to do that.:)