# Suppress or manage "duplicate-entry" errors in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Is there a way to set the equivalent of "insert ignore" in cakephp? I don't want to use the Model->query();. Is there any other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830808/cakephp-insert-ignore-feature

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to suppress duplicates on 1.3:

File: app/app_model.php

```
/**
 * 
 * Callback executed when a save has failed.
 * Contains database error parsing and evaluation to display appropriate messages to end-users.
 * 
 */
private function afterSaveFailed() {
    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig); 
    $lastError = $db->lastError();
    // this holds the match for the key id
    // add more for more database types
    $dupe_check=array(
        'mysql' => '/^\d+: Duplicate entry \'.*\' for key (\d+)$/i',
        'postgres' => '/^ERROR:  duplicate key value violates .+ "(.+)"$/i',
    );
    // this holds the match for the key id
    // add more for more database types
    $foreign_check=array(
        'postgres' => '/^ERROR:  insert or update on table "(.+)" violates foreign key constraint .+/i',
    );
    if(preg_match($dupe_check[$db->config['driver']], $lastError, $matches) 
        && !empty($dupe_check[$db->config['driver']])) {
        $matches[1] = str_replace('_key','',$matches[1]);
        $matches[1] = str_replace($this->table.'_','',$matches[1]);
        $this->invalidate('db','Error: Duplicate value found.');
        return;
    }
    if(preg_match($foreign_check[$db->config['driver']], $lastError, $matches) 
        && !empty($foreign_check[$db->config['driver']])) {
        $this->invalidate('db','Error: Referenced value not found.');
        return;
    }
}
```